# In Java, why doesn't frame.repaint work in this code?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm not sure why the `fr.repaint();` method isn't working here. If I use the set visible `false`, then set it `true` after making changes it makes the screen go black which isn't what I'm trying to do.

Any help?

This code is for a school project, so if it's possible please provide somewhat detailed explanation to understand.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Main {
    static int startingposx;
    static int startingposy;

    static int endingposx;
    static int endingposy;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame fr = new JFrame();
        fr.setBounds(10,10,512,512);
        
        fr.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            }
        });

        fr.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                
                
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                startingposx = e.getX();
                startingposy = e.getY();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

                endingposx = e.getX();
                endingposy = e.getY();
                //fr.setVisible(false);// i tried to use this to refresh it but it makes the frame black for a second
                
                JPanel x = new JPanel(){
                    @Override
                    public void paint(Graphics g){
                            g.setColor(Color.RED);
                            g.fillRect(startingposx-(32-15),startingposy-32,30,30);
                            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                            g.fillRect(endingposx-(32-15),endingposy-32,30,30); 
                    }
                };
                
                fr.add(x);
                fr.repaint();// why does this not work??
                //fr.setVisible(true);
        
                
                System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");
                System.out.println("starting pos: " + startingposx+ ","+ startingposy+"\n" + "ending pos: " + endingposx+ "," + endingposy);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            }
            
            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            }
        });
        
        fr.setVisible(true);        
        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }
}
```

Comment: mouseReleased is called on the event handling thread. Place the code inside `SwingUtilies.invokeLater(() { ... });`. But more important: a missing layout `fr.setLayout(...)` and adding a JPanel on a mouse release is heavy. Better have one JPanel which draws a list of Shapes.

Comment: 1) `JPanel x = new JPanel()` this should be instantiated and added to the frame when it is constructed. 2) `public void paint(Graphics g){` should be `public void paintComponent(Graphics g){` and either should immediately call the `super.paint..` method. 3) `class Main` If not for your sake in 3 months when you revisit this code and wonder WTF this `Main` is, give it a distinct name (like `TestCustomPaint`) for people trying the code right now. I have one package for test code, and it already has a `Main` class in it.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

<sub>Frame made shorter in height purely to save space in answer</sub>

See further comments in the code. Note that the blue rectangle completely covers the red rectangle.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestCustomPaint {
    // Don't use static! Make them instances of the x class and give it a constructor
    static int startingposx;
    static int startingposy;

    static int endingposx;
    static int endingposy;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame fr = new JFrame();
        // this is the wrong size if the content should be square
        fr.setBounds(10,10,512,512);

        // unused MouseMotionListener removed
        fr.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                startingposx = e.getX();
                startingposy = e.getY();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                endingposx = e.getX();
                endingposy = e.getY();

                fr.repaint();

                System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");
                System.out.println("starting pos: " + startingposx+ ","+ startingposy+"\n" +
                        "ending pos: " + endingposx+ "," + endingposy);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) { }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { }
        });

        // This is when the panel should be created and added.
        JPanel x = new JPanel(){
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                g.fillRect(startingposx-(32-15),startingposy-32,30,30);
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                g.fillRect(endingposx-(32-15),endingposy-32,30,30);
            }
        };

        fr.add(x);
        fr.setVisible(true);
        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```